# how to change the existing printed line in AWK

Tags: shell, awk

When i execute the following line, its prints the words in newline.

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "line one\nline two\nline three" }'
```

How can i print the info in the same line with flush the existing line?

For example, while executing the loop, it should print 'one' then wipe out the line and prints 'two' then wipe out the line and prints 'three' etc. can you please assist me?

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the newlines `\n` to carriage returns `\r` (whether this works depends somewhat on your terminal settings). Oh, and print a bunch of trailing whitespace to wipe-out the previous line, and use `printf` to avoid the automatic `\n` that `print` always adds.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { printf "line one    \r" }'; sleep 2; awk 'BEGIN {printf "line two   \r" }'
```

Answer (score 0):

By *"wipe out the line"*, I'm assuming you were referring to a [carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) which can be expressed using the `\r` escape sequence.

For example:

```
[me@home]$ awk 'BEGIN { print "line one\rline two\rline three" }'
line three
```

"line one" and "line two" disappear as they have been *wiped out* and replaced by "line three".

If you wish to have the text visible for a certain time before it gets wiped out, you'll need to insert delays in between each print.

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    printf "line one";
    system("sleep 1");
    printf "\rline two";
    system("sleep 1");
    printf "\rline three";
}'
```

or, using a loop

```
echo "one two three" | awk '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
       printf "\rline %s", $i;
       system("sleep 1");
   }
}'
```